# Pulling data from multiple mysql tables

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

Hello I am creating an API for my android application and pulling posts from database so far I successfully pull the posts with its photo and caption yet I have no idea how to pull the posts user profile picture and username which are stored in my users table. Please anyone to point me in the right direction would be a saviour. This is the code I use in php to pull the post's details

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 // output data of each row
while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$tem = $row;

$json = json_encode($tem);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a join. A good reference for the basics can be found on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Basically (and without knowing the details of your database) there has to be a connecting ID in both tables, in this case a user id. For example:

```
SELECT
  Posts.id,
  Posts.user_id,
  Posts.caption,
  Posts.photo,
  Users.user_id,
  Users.username,
  Users.profile_pic
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Users ON (Users.user_id = Posts.user_id);
```

This will get every post and for each post it will fetch the relevant line(s) from the Users table (where the user_id is the same as in the post).

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. From here I'd study everything else because I'm the kind who learns by trial and error. Thanks a lot @onik